# Private Variables initialization

Tags: java

I ran the below code:

```
public class Box {

    private int length = 1;
    private int width = 2;
    private int height = 3;

     Box(int l, int w, int h) {
            length = l;
            width = w;
            height = h;
        }

        double volume() {
            return length * width * height;
        }

}
```

---

```
public class DemoBox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Box box1 = new Box(3, 3, 3);
        System.out.println("Volumne: " +box1.volume());
    }
}
```

I always thought i wont be able to modify the values of private variables without getter/setter. But in the code above, i was able to pass values to private variables and the result volume came to be 27 (3*3*3). Is this expected behavior and pls explain where I am missing in my understanding in Private variables and also getters/setters

Comment: Go back and read about private variables some more. You can access them within the class in which they are declared. `volume()` is an instance method of `Box` and therefore can access them

Comment: You can only assign to private variables like that. Getters/setters generaly defined public because of accessing form other classes.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass them directly. You passed them in the Constructor, which is expected behavior. Note that the values are being changed in the code of the Constructor, which is contained in the class where these private fields are declared.

Try doing `box1.length = 10` in the `DemoBox` class and see what your compiler says.

Answer (score 1):

All is fine, you CAN **set** this value this way (by **constructor**) only ONCE - on constructing object. After this you variables are safe, no one can change values.

`Box` is not object, this is class definition!

```
public class Box {
...
}
```

`box1` is object, after construction there is no way to change it (without magic) :)

```
Box box1 = new Box(3, 3, 3);
```

If you want result of method `value()` to be 8, then you MUST define another object:

```
Box box2 = new Box(2, 2, 2);
```

After this `box2.value() == 8`.

There is no way to make `box1.value() == 8` (without some magic).

But you can declare fields as final to protect declared values

```
private final int length = 1;
private final int width = 2;
private final int height = 3;
```

After this you cant modify his values even in constructor - compilation failure occurs.

**Getter** gives others permission to read value after creation time. **Setter** gives others permission to modify value after creation time. Without this your fields are safe.

Answer (score 1):

private variables can be modified by the classes internals if they are not final.  In your case the constructor of you class is overriding your default values.  This is both valid and common.

Answer (score 0):

Any code within the scope of the `Box` class can modify and/or read variables declared `private` within the scope of the `Box` class.  In fact that is how getters and setters work; they are within the scope of the class and the access `private` variables.

When you say `Box box1 = new Box(3, 3, 3);` in `DemoBox`, the `DemoBox` code didn't modify the variables, the `Box` constructor did, and the `Box` constructor is within the scope of the class so it can access `private` variables.

Code in `DemoBox` cannot directly modify private variables in `Box`; any `public` methods in `Box` would allow `DemoBox` to modify them indirectly, through the method's code that is within the scope of the `Box` class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the expected behaviour. You are modifying the variables but inside the class they belong, in the way it is described inside the class. What you cannot do is get the variable like `box1.length` or set its value like `box1.length = 5`. It is like Box is the only one that can finally decide if you can get the variable value or set it and how. You can set length value from outside because Box "wanted it", because you allow it in Box constructor (or in another method, it would be the same case).

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your member variables like

```
private int length = 1;
private int width = 2;
private int height = 3;
```

You're just providing defaults that can be overridden with different values passed through a constructor.

```
Box box1 = new Box(3, 3, 3);
```

But, then for this to make sense you also need to supply a **default** Constructor.

```
Box() {}
```

Without a default constructor there's no point in providing default values for your member variables as they would always get overwritten by your parameterized constructor.

```
Box defaultBox = new Box();
System.out.println("Volumne: " + box1.volume()); // prints 6; default volume
```

Now, the reason you were able to modify private variables is that you did so from within the constructor; a special class construct that initializes the state of the object being constructed. The private access modifier does not apply here because what you're protecting as private needs to be constructed first!

Answer (score 0):

Private variables can be modified within the class where they are defined. From a class other than the one where the variables are defined we cannot modify private variables without setter.